# Error capturing JWT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

I am working on jwt angular + java jersey authentication. I am able to send jwt token back from server to client which can be seen as POST response with status code 200 in the chrome console.

My problem is I am not able to save it in a variable so that I can perform decoding. I get an error like this:

```
TypeError: href is null
e/<()angular.min.js (line 107)
Ze/this.$get</<()angular.min.js (line 81)
f/<()angular.min.js (line 119)
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$eval()angular.min.js (line 133)
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$digest()angular.min.js (line 130)
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$apply()angular.min.js (line 134)
g()angular.min.js (line 87)
T()angular.min.js (line 92)
Uf/</w.onload()angular.min.js (line 93)
stackFrame.js (line 357)
<System>
error is:undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http)
{
$scope.email = "";
$scope.password = "";

$scope.loginForm = function () {
    var data = {email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password};
    var url = 'rs/loginResource';
        $http.post(url, data).success(function (response)
        {
            console.log("token is: " + response);
        }).error(function (error)
        {
            console.log("error is:" + error);
        });
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending token in JSON? or as plain text?

I recently used jwt based authentication on HAM stack, and served the token in object, so response was something like { token: 'asdasds.sdadad.asdad' }, I usually make call to server in Angular in the following form:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'rs/loginResource',
    data: {
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    }
})
.then(function (resp) {
    var token = resp.data.token
})
.catch(function(error){
    return error;
});
```

Comment: I am sending the token using `Response.ok(token).build();` method of jersery. I guess automatic response builder functionality of jax-rs jersey is causing the problem. The token is just coming in form like this: `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbGljZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9jMmlkLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ1MTQxNDU0MH0
.HvguthVdVZ8IuP6Hsko95I70jB41jpZLqAC4VAmphDJcnRwdBBkeVBVS8RNP9z1J1c7bjzeXL5gaufr6P02GhoMwh37l58Sxzwu
8dyxLZOyyEI7A03yZkmXzRKi_TPPG-vQR6Ya9omUPioG1mPU9ZOI4XTuZooRyxph8uh9JJfw`

Comment: Are you using java jersey as your backend?

Comment: No, I'm using Hapijs on Nodejs as backend, but in fact it doesn't matter, only important thing is how response object looks like, when you receive it in angular. I just noticed you're using .success(function(response)) to receive the resolved promise. Can you replace it with .then(function(response))?

Comment: and replace .error(function(error)) with .catch(function(error))

Comment: Its ok I figured out how to capture the token and save it in a variable and now the problem is I am not able to decode it at client side. I am using nimbus jose+jwt http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-signature